# Umbraco and Telerik MVC

Tags: umbraco, telerik-mvc

Is this possible to install and use Telerik Extension for ASP.NET MVC in Umbraco project? If "yes", what is a best way to do this.

I try to install but have some errors, eg:

```
'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for
'Telerik' and the best extension method overload 
'Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.HtmlHelperExtension.Telerik(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper)' 
 has some invalid arguments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your using Umbraco 4.7.1 or below, which is based on ASP.NET Web Forms (not MVC). If this is the case you wont be able to use any of the Telerik MVC Extensions.

You may be able to use some of the Telerik controls for ASP.NET AJAX, but I've never tried that myself.